# Accessing master Mac from other rooms

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing, remote-control

I have an office/studio setup with MacBook Pro 2017 with 2 external monitors attached to it.

I'd like to have a second (non-primary) laptop, no need to be as powerful as my main machine and I'd like use it for remote access to the primary machine from anywhere in the house at any time.

I know I can use a Screen Sharing option, however, I can't remotely connect when the primary machine is in a sleep mode.

Let's say that if the sleep mode wouldn't be a problem then I'm facing another problem and that is the two monitors. If I remotely Screen Share to the primary machine my secondary machine will see two screens.

Is there a way to Screen Share/Remote Access to the primary machine and to see just one screen that adjusts its resolution?

Or, is they a way that I can remotely connect to my primary machine whilst my machine is always in a sleep mode and that when I'm connected to it then the two monitors won't get activated at all or the computer would not wake up? Maybe a thin client?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I'm curious...your *main* computer is a laptop.  Why not just take that with you instead of getting another laptop to connect to it?  The next question is..what do you want to do remotely?  Use apps on that laptop or just access the data that lives on the main?  What about *sharing* the data and having the same app on both computers?

Comment: the main one is a laptop, but I have many cables and leads around so I treat that as a desktop computer. I have a small home audio studio and at the same time I'm a developer. so sometimes I just want to be in another room and carry on where I left off with my applications without constant fiddling with wires and readjusting the screens back, etc. I remember ages ago I worked in a corporation and from whichever floor you logged in the state of the desktop and the apps were where I last used them. it was cool, but it was on windows. not sure Mac can do that?